# how to manually add a node in drupal 7 in the database

Tags: database

I have managed to display the title but im missing the body of the title. i cant find in the database which table i missed to edit.

here's the list of tables i editted:

1. node
2. node_revision
3. node_comment_statistics
4. taxonomy_index

for the body i assume that these fields are responsible for it:

1. field_data_body
2. field_revision_body
3. field_data_taxonomy_forums
4. field_revision_taxonomy_forums

The node i made has no comments so no comment table is editted.

Am i missing other tables to edit here?

SO i assume i have editted all the necessary tables but i seemed to have missed something here cause **ONLY THE BODY IS MISSING.**

Comment: can you see the node in the admin section `admin/content`?

Comment: yes i can view the node i have made. but the body is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are trying to understand Drupal database concept, you are checking every insert you made in the Drupal admin section, and by doing so Drupal is caching your data.

So you are not missing anything. You only need to clear Drupal cache, try to truncate each cache table one by one.

Comment: Thank you sir that solved my problem. Another question, can you skip the revision table? will the data still display? if yes then will it have a bad side effect?

Comment: @Belmark - Most of the information you view actually is retrieved from the revision tables. So the answers to your two questions are, respectively, no, do not skip revision tables, and yes, bad.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is just an academic exercise to better understand Drupal storage.

If you have the nid of the page, go to /node/{insert NID}/edit (or use the Edit tab), and make your changes there. Then go to the database and see where the changes took place. Pay particular attention to the vid (Version ID) as it may or may not match the Node ID. Your assumptions about the tables involved are correct.

Comment: you again LOL. I know how to edit drupal on its UI. i want to learn the database concept of it. Your process of understanding the database is what i did, but i seem to have missed something cause only the body of the manually added node is missing