# How to retrieve node body from nid with an SQL query in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, entities, database

From [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6787/where-does-drupal-store-the-content-of-a-nodes-body) I learned that I have to look in `field_data_body` to retrieve the body of a node from a database.

`field_data_body` does not have an `nid` field though.

What query can I use to retrieve the body from an `nid`?

To clarify: I simply wanted to quickly fetch a text from a database dump without installing the dump on an actual site. So not looking for PHP here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> field_data_body does not have an nid field though.

Because a field can be attached to any entity, which may have a different primary key than nid.

If you **really** must use direct SQL, you can query the field like this

`SELECT body_value FROM field_data_body WHERE entity_type = 'node' AND entity_id = 1`

However, this bypasses several of Drupal's layers, so it's normally strongly discouraged to use direct queries.

Instead, it's better to

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->propertyCondition('status', NODE_PUBLISHED)
  ->propertyCondition('nid', 1)
;
$result = $query->execute();

$nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($result['node']));

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $bodies = field_get_items('node', $node, 'body');
  foreach ($bodies as $body) {
    var_dump($body['safe_value']);
  }
}
```

The EFQ version have several advantages

1. It's safe. You can't (easily) accidentally open injection attacks.
2. It outputs a safely escaped value, avoiding XSS attacks.
3. It works if a node has multiple values for the body field.
4. It works on sites with multiple languages.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because `field_data_body` can be associated with entities that are not nodes, you need to look at the `entity_id` field as equivalent to the `nid` field.

If it's a node's body content you're trying to query, then I would run `` db_query('SELECT body_value FROM `field_data_body` where entity_id = :nid, array(":nid" => $nid)); ``

Answer (score -1):

In general, all entities are fieldable. Thus, the table `field_data_body` holds data for all `body` fields, regardless of being attached to a node or a comment. Hence, the column you are looking for is `entity_id` (with `entity_type = 'node'`).

On a side node, you shouldn't tamper with the database in such a way, just use

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$body = node->body['und'][0]['value'];
```

to get the body (exact code of course depends on your site setup in terms of language, etc.).

Comment: please don't recommend `->body['und'][0]['value']` but use `field_get_items` instead.